# Bundler says the bundle is ok but won't run the code

Tags: ruby, bundler

When I run bundle check, it says:

```
ubuntu@ip:/opt/bluecopper/current$ /opt/default-ruby/bundle check
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
```

When I list gems I get:

```
ubuntu@ip:/opt/bluecopper/current$ /opt/default-ruby/bundle list
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Gems included by the bundle:
  * aws-sdk-v1 (1.64.0)
  * bluecopper (0.1.0)
  * bundler (1.10.5)
  * dotenv (2.0.2)
  * json (1.8.3)
  * mini_portile (0.6.2)
  * multi_json (1.11.1)
  * nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
  * rollbar (1.5.3)
  * thor (0.19.1)
```

But when I actually try to `exec` something it says:

```
ubuntu@ip:/opt/bluecopper/current$ /opt/default-ruby/ruby -S bundle exec bluecopper start -c app-config.yml 
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Could not find json-1.8.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bluecopper` executable had a shebang with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

This, when called with `bundle exec` made the command use the system ruby instead of the expected `/opt/default-ruby/ruby`, the fix was to change the path to prepend `/opt/default-ruby` so that `/usr/bin/env ruby` would pick up the right one.

Answer (score 2):

In the first two commands you were using `/opt/default-ruby/bundle` but in the last one `/opt/default-ruby/ruby -S bundle`.

I would try to use `/opt/default-ruby/bundle exec bluecopper start -c app-config.yml`. It might be related with `ruby -S` changing $PATH.